# Stacked bar chart to show asset maintenance types by year

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, data-visualization, bar-chart

I have a table of roads by year.

The NEXT_ACTIVITY column categorizes the roads by the theoretical maintenance activity that the roads fall into.

```
    YEAR  COUNT/TOTAL   ROAD_COUNT    NEXT_ACTIVITY
    ----  ----------   -----------    ------------------
    2013      77.43%         1185     None/Good
    2013      17.05%          261     Overlay
    2013       2.16%           33     Full Depth Removal
    2013       3.36%           51     Reconstruction

    2014      73.84%         1130     None/Good
    2014      20.54%          314     Overlay
    2014       2.38%           36     Full Depth Removal
    2014       3.23%           49     Reconstruction

    2015      64.21%          983     None/Good
    2015      28.80%          441     Overlay
    2015       3.69%           56     Full Depth Removal
    2015       3.30%           50     Reconstruction

    2016      65.06%          997     None/Good
    2016      28.58%          438     Overlay
    2016       3.62%           55     Full Depth Removal
    2016       2.74%           42     Reconstruction

    2017      63.71%          977     None/Good
    2017      29.67%          455     Overlay
    2017       4.01%           61     Full Depth Removal
    2017       2.61%           40     Reconstruction

    2018      62.19%          954     None/Good
    2018      30.15%          462     Overlay
    2018       4.92%           75     Full Depth Removal
    2018       2.74%           42     Reconstruction

    2019      61.51%          943     None/Good
    2019      29.82%          457     Overlay
    2019       5.93%           91     Full Depth Removal
    2019       2.74%           42     Reconstruction

    2020      60.27%          924     None/Good
    2020      30.54%          468     Overlay
    2020       6.62%          101     Full Depth Removal
    2020       2.57%           39     Reconstruction

    2021      58.31%          894     None/Good
    2021      30.87%          473     Overlay
    2021       7.86%          120     Full Depth Removal
    2021       2.97%           45     Reconstruction

    2022      58.31%          894     None/Good
    2022      30.87%          473     Overlay
    2022       7.86%          120     Full Depth Removal
    2022       2.97%           45     Reconstruction
```

---

In Excel 2016, I want to graph the data in a **stacked bar chart**.

- YEAR as the X-axis
- COUNT/TOTAL (percentage) as the Y-axis
- Each bar (year) would be composed of four categories (sub-bars):

  - None/Good
  - Overlay
  - Full Depth Removal
  - Reconstruction

I think it would look something like this (not totally accurate):

[image]

---

**Question:**

How can I make a stacked bar chart like that in Excel 2016?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to modify how your data appear and then you can create the stacked bar chart from your modified data. You can keep your original data as-is, but then use another sheet to get the proper format for your chart.

**Easiest Solution**: Create a pivot table on your data. Then create the chart from the pivot table. Just select your data and insert pivot table. Rows is Year, Columns is Next Activity, and Values is Count/Total column.

**More cumbersome but viable solution**: Use formulas to get your data. See below...

Column E: Distinct Year

Cells F1:I1: Your Four categories as they appear in Column C. You'll use a formula to populate the data below it.

```
Cell F2 formula: =SUMIFS($B:$B,$A:$A,$E2,$C:$C,F$1)
```

With those locked references, you can drag it across and down then generate your chart from this array.

[image]

IMHO, use a Pivot table. It's super quick and you can adjust the design of the chart to remove the buttons, etc. You just need to refresh the pivot when new data are added. Also, convert your data into a Table. That way you don't need to modify the selected area when updating your pivot.